# How to implement a ResideMenu on jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, menu, slidingdrawer

I would like to implement a ResideMenu just like the image, here is the link:

http://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/107759/screenshots/1114754/social_feed_ios7.gif

Please, any help or component?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to setup the following:

1. Transition CSS3 classes `transform3d`, `scale3d` and `transition`.
2. Create a div with contents any place in body outside *page div*.
3. Apply changes on *active page* pre-animation and revert all defaults post-animation.

---

1. **ResideMenu content div and related styles:**

   Create a div and place it in body. Make sure `position: absolute;` and low `z-index: -9999;`, as that div shouldn't be visible/clickable even if its *hidden*.

   HTML

   ```
   <div id="content">
     <!-- content -->
   </div>
   ```

   CSS

   ```
   #content {
     height: 100%;
     width: 50%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 5px;
     left: 5px;
     z-index: -9999;
   }
   ```
2. **Transformation and animation:**

   Create three classes; showing, hiding and animating the aforementioned steps.

   Animation class - you can play with animation speed `500ms`.

   ```
   .panel-animate {
       -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
       -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
       -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
       transition: all 500ms ease;
   }
   ```

   Menu showing/revealing class - page is moved `60%` on *X-Axis* and scaled down by `60%` of its' *width* and *height*. You can play with those values as well.

   ```
   .panel-open {
       -webkit-transform: translate3d(60%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 1);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(60%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 1);
       -ms-transform: translate3d(60%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 1);
       -o-transform: translate3d(60%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 1);
       transform: translate3d(60%, 0, 0) scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 1);
   }
   ```

   Menu hiding class.

   ```
   .panel-close {
       -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
       -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
       transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
   }
   ```
3. **Code to show/hide menu:**

   First step, if ResideMenu contains any jQuery Mobile *widgets*, they should be initialized manually since the reside outside *page* div. To manually initialize/create jQM widget, call `.enhanceWithin()` on parent div, then *hide* ResideMenu div.

   ```
   $("#content").enhanceWithin().hide();
   ```

   Showing ResideMenu - consists of four steps.

   **1)** Hide *Y-Axis* overflow on *body* to avoid scroll once menu is shown. **2)** Update page's height according to *viewport*'s height. If toolbars (header/footer) are used in that page, *88px* (top & bottom padding) should be subtracted from *viewport*'s height. If either header or footer is used, subtract *44px*. **3)** Apply animation classes to show the menu. **4)** Unhide menu div.

   ```
   $(".panel").on("click", function () {
      $("body").css({ "overflow-y": "hidden" });
      $(".ui-page-active").height($(window).height() - 88);
      $(".ui-page-active").addClass("panel-animate panel-open");
      $("#content").show();
   });
   ```

   Hiding ResideMenu - simple step, just remove opening class and add closing class. However, note that menu's `z-index` should be changed again to low value. Because when it's shown, `z-index` is set to high value, explanation will come in next setp.

   ```
   $(".panel-close-btn").on("click", function () {
      $(".ui-page-active").addClass("panel-close").removeClass("panel-open");
      $("#content").css("z-index", "-9999");
   });
   ```

   Changes to be made in between the previous two steps. These changes should be applied after animation/transition is done by listening to `transitionend` event.

   **1)** If menu is revealed, its' `z-index` should be set to high value in order to become clickable/touchable. **2)** If menu is closed/hidden, it should be *hidden* after transition is done. **3)** Remove ALL custom CSS applied to both *body* and *active page*. **4)** Add back header/footer *88px padding* to *active page* and remove closing & animating classes. **5)** Since *active page*'s height is modified prior to revealing the menu, it should be returned as it was before by calling `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight()`.

   ```
   $(document).on("webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend transitionend msTransitionEnd", ".panel-open, .panel-close", function (e) {
       if ($(this).hasClass("panel-open")) {
           $("#content").css("z-index", "9999");
       }
       if ($(this).hasClass("panel-close")) {
           $("#content").hide();
           $("body, .ui-page-active").removeAttr("style");
           $(this).removeClass("panel-animate panel-close").css({ padding: "44px 0" });
           $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();
       }
   });
   ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nc2Ps/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1)</sup> Tested on Safari & Chrome for Mobile - iPhone 5 and iPad 2.

Comment: @Eusthace es un placer ;)